# how to call one action in another action(whose ajax layout is disabled) in same controller in zend

Tags: zend-framework

How to call one action in another action(whose ajax layout is disabled for checking existence)
in same controller in zend.I have checked existence already and array print using json but when isbn not exist in database then we have to call another action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the result of another action in an action method, you can try to use [Action View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action) like this:

```
public function youractionAction() {
    /* code before the call to another action */
    $view_helper = new Zend_View_Helper_Action();
    $html_content = $view_helper->action('otheraction', 'samecontroller', 'samemodule'); // content of the result of another action
    /* code afterthe call to another action */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forward to move to other action (this will also change your view)

```
$this->_forward('index');
```